# Multi selection listbox vba

Tags: vba, listbox, multi-select

I have some listboxes in a form with multi selection allowed. I need to associate the options selected to variables.
I tried this:

```
For i = 0 To (ListBox7.Items.Count - 1)
            If ListBox7.Selected(i) = True Then
                If maq1 = "" Then
                    maq1 = ListBox7.GetItemText(i)
                Else
                    maq2 = ListBox7.GetItemText(i)
                End If
            End If
Next
```

and this:

```
For i = 0 To (ListBox7.Items.Count - 1)
            If ListBox7.SelectedItem(i) Then
                If maq1 = "" Then
                    maq1 = ListBox7.GetItemText(i)
                Else
                    maq2 = ListBox7.GetItemText(i)
                End If
            End If
Next
```

But nothing is working. In the first case, i got an error "selected is not a member of listbox" and in the second one i got "the conversion of type 'Char' to 'Boolean' is not valid".
does anyone can help me? thanks :)

Comment: Try declaring variables like this `Dim maq1 As String, maq2 As String`

Comment: I have already declared the variables. I forgot to put it in the code here.

Comment: I concur with what @FunThomas has written - wanted to post pretty much the same thing when I saw his answer. BUT where does `GetItemText` come from? This is NOT Office Forms VBA. Are you using a third-party control?

Comment: what do you mean with "a third-party control"..i'm sorry but i am not a programmer

Comment: How did you add the ListBox to the UserForm? EXACTLY which steps did you follow? Also, can you make a screenshot of the "toolbox" in the VBA Editor where the controls for the UserForm are provided?

Comment: Note: In order to get someone's attention you need to include their name in your reply. I didn't see your response because you didn't "ping" me. Address a person like this, with an ampersand: @PaulaLopes

Answer (score 0):

For me, this code works, but note that following your logic , `maq1` holds the *first* selected value and `maq2` then *last* (if more that one value was selected). I don't know if this is what you really want...

```
Dim i As Integer, maq1 As String, maq2 As String
For i = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1

    If Me.ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
        If maq1 = "" Then
            maq1 = Me.ListBox1.List(i)
        Else
            maq2 = Me.ListBox1.List(i)
        End If
    End If
Next i
```

`Selected` is an array of boolean telling if an item is selected or not. `List` holds the items itself. So if `Selected(i)` is `true`, `List(i)` is selected.

Comment: I tried your code and this was what i get:

'selected is not a member of listbox'
'listcount is not a member of listbox'
'list is not a member of listbox'

Comment: And `listbox` is really a ListBox?

Comment: Yes. I already tried a lot of differente codes, but nothing seems to work :/

Comment: Maybe i have to add some reference that I don't know :/

Comment: No, listBox comes out of the box in VBA forms, no need to reference anything. My suspicion is similar to what Cindy wrote in her comment.

Answer (score 0):

@CindyMeister
To creat the listboxes i just selected listbox from the toolbox and created it
[Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAAH4.png)This is my form. And this is the code to fill de listboxes:

```
 While folhaexcel.Cells(contador, 1).text <> ""
            maquina = folhaexcel.Cells(contador, 1).text
            grupo = folhaexcel.Cells(contador, 4).text
            status = folhaexcel.Cells(contador, 2).text

            If status = "OFF" And grupo = "Climatic Chambers" Then

                ListBox1.Items.Add(maquina)


            ElseIf status = "OFF" And grupo = "Thermal Shock Chamber" Then

                ListBox2.Items.Add(maquina)


            ElseIf status = "OFF" And grupo = "Temperature Chamber" Then

                ListBox3.Items.Add(maquina)


            ElseIf status = "OFF" And grupo = "Acoustic Machine" Then

                If maquina = "m32" Then
                    ListBox5.Items.Add("m32 + m35")

                ElseIf maquina = "m35" Then

                Else
                    ListBox5.Items.Add(maquina)

                End If


            ElseIf status = "OFF" And grupo = "Fall Machine" Then

                ListBox6.Items.Add(maquina)

            ElseIf status = "OFF" And grupo = "Electric Equipment" Then

                ListBox7.Items.Add(maquina)

            ElseIf status = "OFF" And grupo = "Vibration + Temperature" Then

                If maquina = "m1" Then
                    ListBox4.Items.Add("m1 + m2")

                ElseIf maquina = "m2" Then

                ElseIf maquina = "m3" Then

                    ListBox4.Items.Add("m3 + m89")

                ElseIf maquina = "m89" Then

                ElseIf maquina = "m27" Then

                    ListBox4.Items.Add("m27 + m28")

                ElseIf maquina = "m28" Then

                ElseIf maquina = "m90" Then

                    ListBox4.Items.Add("m90 + m93")

                ElseIf maquina = "m93" Then

                Else

                    ListBox4.Items.Add(maquina)

                End If


            End If

            contador = contador + 1

        End While
```

and this is working well. But now i have to associate the machines that i select in each listbox to variables but i can't.

[toolbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60dTf.png)

Comment: Your screenshot suggest that you are using Visual Basic .Net, not VBA?!?

Comment: Also, as a general advice at Stackoverflow: Update your question to add new information. An answer is meant to be an *answer* to the question.